# PHP/Garbage collection, unsetting variable

Tags: php, garbage-collection

Does anybody have an explanation to this weird behavior of php?
Basically, I made a variable $number, and than made a variable `$num2`, which is a ref to `$number`. So I thought they will both share the same memory location.

But when I unset `$number`, its still outputs .. , I thought that if I would use some gc commands it will clear it cause it looks like heap behavior. But it's still not working. :P

```
function sum(&$var) {
    $var++;
}
$number = 5;
$num2 = &$number;
sum($number);
echo $number; echo '<br>';
gc_enable();
gc_collect_cycles();
sleep(5);
unset($number);
echo $num2;
```

Comment: From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php): "When you unset the reference, you just break the binding between variable name and variable content. This does not mean that variable content will be destroyed."

Comment: There are no "memory locations" in PHP - there's no pointers. a reference is SOMEWHAT like a C-code pointer, but not exactly the same, and your expected behavior for pointers cannot be applied to php references.

Comment: Hey Marc, so what extacly happening if there are no mem locations?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP when you unset a variable that another variable is referenced to (this is what occurs in your case), it simply breaks the link connecting those variables, but remains the value in the second variable.

This [is described in the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php).

> $mainVar = "Hello!";
>   $linkedVar = &$mainVar;
>   unset($mainVar);

So even after `$mainVar` is unset, the `$linkedVar` retains that value.

Comment: So after first variable is unset , it makes a copy to the ref one, did i get you right?

Comment: Basically, a better way to think of it is that a PHP reference is a link that is continuously copying the value of the mainVar to the linkedVar, but once the mainVar is destroyed, the link is too.  So the linkedVar's value stays the same as the last value of the mainVar before its destruction.

Comment: So basically var 2 keeps track of 1 for modifications and change according to it. and when 1 is unset it loses connection , means 2 is not tracking anymore

Comment: basically.  PHP is a bit odd sometimes